# Local Product Struture

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, reference-request

Let be $\Lambda$ a hosrseshoe for a $C^r$  ($r\geq2$) dipheomorphism $f:M\to M$  where   $M$ is  a two dimensional manifold. A well-known result is the following:

for each $x\in \Lambda$  let be $W^u(x)$ and $W^s(x)$ the unstable and stable manifolds respectively of  $f$   in $x$. Then exists neighborhoods $\mathcal{V}_1$ and $\cal{V}_2$ of $\Lambda$ where are defined $C^1$ foliations $\cal{F}_1$ and $\cal{F}_2$ 
such that $T_p\mathcal{F}_1=E^u_p$ and $T_p\mathcal{F}_2=E^s_p$ where $T_p\mathcal{F}_i$ denotes
the tangent space  on the leave $\cal{F}_i$.

My question is: how construct  this foliations ?

Comment: See this question:  http://mathoverflow.net/questions/27516/local-product-structure-horseshoes

Comment: To summarise the answer from that question... the argument is on p. 166 of Palis and Takens' book:  http://books.google.com/books?id=pwydPA23KVUC&printsec=frontcover&dq=palis+takens+hyperbolicity&hl=es&cd=1#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: Hi Vaughn! I knew this reference, but it does not say much for me beyond the result itself. I'm looking for something more concrete.
I want to believe that this result is not just part of folklore.
Sorry if I do not understand out of ignorance.

Comment: There are a few typos in your title and question body.

Comment: Yeah, there seem to be typos; its *diffeomorphism*, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find an alternative proof (to the one of Palis Takens) in section 6.4 of [this survey](http://arxiv.org/PS_cache/arxiv/pdf/0912/0912.2896v1.pdf).